# Randomly my application gets crashed when device is in idle state

Tags: android

Some times my app randomly crashed when device is in idle state. I can not see any crashing inside logs. I am posting the logs, some body please look and give your valuable ideas.

```
07-23 13:03:17.265: I/ActivityManager(1004): START u0 {cmp=com.myApp/.A} from pid 19595
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004): startActivityUncheckedLocked: task left null
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004): java.lang.RuntimeException: here
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1651)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1254)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:746)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3222)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3208)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:136)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2136)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
07-23 13:03:17.265: V/ActivityManager(1004):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

P.S : I just wanted to know whether this can make app crash or not ??

Comment: I don't get any information of your log, but if your app get crashed on idle state you need check onPause, onStop and onSavedInstanceState

Comment: it was crashed and restarted again, i am using background service. only this exception i found odd in complete logs else every thing looks fine.

Comment: I read a post about a similar problem (without solution), but it must have something to do with any use of an intent. What are You doing with Your app, is there any service in the background?